# mssql select from multiple tables with sum

Tags: select, sum, multiple-tables

Using MSSQL 2008R2. Need to create a select to later create a view. Have 3 tables. Table Emply has a one to one with table User. Table Emply has one to many to table sales_lines.

Table: Emply

```
id   Hourly_rate
1   12.50
2   19.00
```

Table: USER

```
ID   Name
1    BoB Smith
2    Mary Jones
```

Table: Sales_Lines

```
ID   AMOUNT   DATE_SALE
1   10.00    01/12/2017
2    5.00    01/15/2017
1   15.00    01/12/2017
1   30.00    01/01/2017
```

The output should show total sales per day per user ID

```
ID   Name       Total_Sales   Date
1    Bob Smith    25.00       01/12/2017
1    Bob Smith    30.00       01/01/2017
2    Mary Jones    5.00       01/15/2017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to join the two tables and group them afterwards.

```
SELECT s.ID, SUM(s.AMOUNT), s.DATE_SALE
FROM USER u LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales_Lines s
ON u.ID = s.ID
GROUP BY s.DATE_SALE, s.ID;
```

This query would be read as follow:
Get me the user id, sum of amounts and date from the group that is made of every user combined with it's sales_line grouped by the same user and same date.

Comment: Thanks Faegy - When run I get error. USER.ID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY 
clause

Comment: Thanks Faegy, that did it works fine now. I now need to expand this for more tables but this will get me started.

Comment: You're welcome! If you feel like this answer resolved your issue, feel free to accept it. This way users with the same issues will resolve theirs easier.